# Powershell cmdlet in "silent mode" possible?

Tags: powershell

For example when launching

```
Get-PackageProvider -Name Chocolatey
```

You'll have to answer Yes.

How to launch from Batch file without requiring to answer Y ?

Comment: have you tried -ForceBootstrap ?

Comment: @derloopkat ok thanks that's it I didn't know about it. If you write the answer I'll mark it as good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the `Get-PackageProvider` cmdlet documentation, you can skip the prompt by using the `-ForceBootstrap` switch:

```
PS C:\> Get-Help -Name Get-PackageProvider -Parameter ForceBootstrap

-ForceBootstrap [<SwitchParameter>]  
    Indicates that this cmdlet forces Package Management to automatically install
    the package provider.  

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                False
    Accept pipeline input?       False
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Comment: And using just `-Force` is equivalent to `-ForceBootstrap`.

Comment: @lit Only in this cmdlet.